# Text file not openable in custom module

Tags: python, module

I have a module that I've made that reads a text file, and works perfectly when    ran it on its own. However, when run as a module, the file is not found.

The text file is in the same directory as the .py module that's imported

Comment: You should post your code here..

Comment: Please post your code along with traceback/error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The text file is in the same directory as the .py module that's imported

This is your problem. It should be in the same directory as the main script, as that is the current directory when Python is started.

If you want to always read it from the same directory as the module, you can do something like this in the module to get the directory the module is in:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
myfile = open(join(dirname(__file__), "mydatafile.txt"))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you *do* actually want to read the text file from the module file's directory, this will get you the path:

```
import os
import mymodule

nytextfile_path = os.path.dirname(mymodule.__file__) + '/mytextfile.txt'
```